# Classify output value based on different conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, classification

I have written a code in Python which outputs a single value and I want to write a code that classifies that single output value depending on different statements.

My code gives me the value of 'Vk' and I want Python to classify automatically the value and output the statement based on these conditions and ranges:

[image: temen]

I have tried the following but no output was printed:

```
if (Vk = 0):
       st = 'Ideal Homogenous'

if (0 < Vk < 0.25):
       st = 'Slightly Heterogenous'

if (0.25 < Vk < 0.50):
       st = ' Heterogenous'

if (0.50 < Vk < 0.75):
       st = 'Very Heterogenous'

if (0.75 < Vk < 1):
       st = 'Extremely Heterogenous'

if (Vk = 1):
       st = 'Perfectly Heterogenous'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Please read up on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your odds of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`if... elif... else` conditional statements would serve your purpose well.

Make sure to have those ordered correctly so that the program falls to the most specific condition first